# How to List All Badges Except Those Badges Already Completed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, iteration, badge

How can `@badges_available` list all badges from `User.first` (the admin user) except for those badges which have already been completed by current_user? Something like `.where(title != @badges_available.title)`

```
@badges_available = User.first.badges.where.not(title: current_user.badges.title) # undefined method `title' for #<Badge::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fb85a6db2c0>
@badges_completed = @user.badges
```

This way in the view the there is never a duplication of `title`. If an `available` badge is completed then it should only show under `completed` and not `available` anymore.

```
<% @badges_completed.each do |completed| %>
  <%= completed.title %><br>
<% end %>

<% @badges_available.each do |available| %>
  <%= available.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `title: current_user.badges.pluck(:title)` should do.

Comment: How you differentiate *completed badges* from *available badges*? Is there a boolean?

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa that worked!